# How to filter values that appear after another value by group in R?

Tags: r, filter, grouping

I am trying to filter products that customers bought after buying a product "A".

My sample data set:

```
fk_ConsumerID   ProductName Date
1   B   2015.10.12
1   A   2015.10.14
1   C   2015.10.18
1   D   2015.10.19
2   A   2015.10.10
2   B   2015.10.12
2   C   2015.10.14
2   D   2015.10.18
2   E   2015.10.19
3   C   2015.10.14
3   D   2015.10.18
3   A   2015.10.19
4   B   2015.10.10
```

Result I want to get:

```
fk_ConsumerID   ProductName Date
1   C   2015.10.18
1   D   2015.10.19
2   B   2015.10.12
2   C   2015.10.14
2   D   2015.10.18
2   E   2015.10.19
```

Code I tried writing:

```
library(dplyr)
#Grouping customers
customers <- group_by(df, fk_ConsumerId)
#Filtering the ones that appear after A (Doesn`t work)
f<-filter(customers, ProductName > "A")
```

Comment: `filter(customers, ProductName != "A")` this doesn't work?

Comment: It only gives the values that are not equal A. And I want to get the values that are listed after A. I don`t need the ones are before A and I don`t need it if the customer doesn`t have an A at all.

Comment: If you want customers bought after buying a product "A", the result you want to get should be different. There's a third A, so the last entry should be included, shouldn't it?
Edit: I got the point.

Comment: I am only interested in products that are different. Sorry for lack of explanation.

Comment: Is it possible that the purchose history of a customer will include more than one purchase of product `A`? If so, do you want to see all purchases after the first purchase of `A` or after the last purchase of `A`?

Comment: It is possible. I want to see every purchase that happens after every A (except the A itself).

Comment: Another question: Is your data set already sorted by `Date`? _After_ isn't cearly defined. Do you mean by position (i.e. rows) or by `Date`?

Comment: I mean by date and it is already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to find a neater solution, but this is a temporary one that does the job.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(fk_ConsumerID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4),
ProductName=c("B","A","C","D","A","B","C","D","E","C","D","A","B"),
                  Date=c(1:13)
                 )

df <- df %>% group_by(fk_ConsumerID) %>% 
        mutate(cc=ProductName=="A",
               ss=seq_along(ProductName)
               ) 


  fk_ConsumerID ProductName  Date    cc    ss
           <dbl>      <fctr> <int> <lgl> <int>
1              1           B     1 FALSE     1
2              1           A     2  TRUE     2
3              1           C     3 FALSE     3
4              1           D     4 FALSE     4
5              2           A     5  TRUE     1
6              2           B     6 FALSE     2
7              2           C     7 FALSE     3
8              2           D     8 FALSE     4
9              2           E     9 FALSE     5
10             3           C    10 FALSE     1
11             3           D    11 FALSE     2
12             3           A    12  TRUE     3
13             4           B    13 FALSE     1
```

a temp dataframe to list each fk_ConsumerID  and the index of the entry with A:

```
kk <- df[which(df$cc==TRUE),c(1,5)]
names(kk)[2] <- "idx"

> kk
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
Groups: fk_ConsumerID [3]

  fk_ConsumerID   idx
          <dbl> <int>
1             1     2
2             2     1
3             3     3
```

add the index of the entry with A in a new column:

```
getIndex <- function(x){

        kk$idx[kk$fk_ConsumerID==x] %>% 
                as.integer
}
```

filter based on the index value:

```
df <- df %>% 
        mutate(idx=map(fk_ConsumerID,getIndex )) %>% 
        filter(ss>idx) %>% 
        select(1:3)


Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: fk_ConsumerID [2]

  fk_ConsumerID ProductName  Date
          <dbl>      <fctr> <int>
1             1           C     3
2             1           D     4
3             2           B     6
4             2           C     7
5             2           D     8
6             2           E     9
```

Answer (score 0):

Produce temporary variable first, then filter group with productname='A', further filter rank is greater than rank where productname='A' is located.

```
df%>%group_by(fk_ConsumerID)%>%mutate(rank=1:n())%>%
filter(sum(ProductName=='A')>0)%>%filter(rank>rank[ProductName=='A'])%>%
select(-rank)
    # fk_ConsumerID ProductName       Date
              <int>       <chr>      <chr>
    1             1           C 2015.10.18
    2             1           D 2015.10.19
    3             2           B 2015.10.12
    4             2           C 2015.10.14
    5             2           D 2015.10.18
    6             2           E 2015.10.19
```

Comment: I am not sure why, but when I try your way I still get the "A" product after filtering... ;/ And after running the function I receive warning: "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)"

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution in dplyr that solves your problem.
first we find the time a customer bought item a. This time is stored in a new column called timeA.
Now it is just to select all rows that have a time that comes after this time.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(fk_ConsumerID) %>% 
  filter(ProductName=="A") %>%
  summarise(timeA = min(Date)) %>%
  right_join(df) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(timeA),Date > timeA)
```

Answer (score -1):

The following `data.table` ([version 1.9.7](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)) solution uses non-equi joins:

```
library(data.table)
# date of first purchase of product A by each customer
# (thereby removing edge case where purchase of A was the last purchase)
fp <- dt[ProductName == "A" & Date < max(Date), .(minDate = min(Date)), by = fk_ConsumerID]
# non-equi join 
dt[fp, on = c("fk_ConsumerID", "Date>minDate")]

#   fk_ConsumerID ProductName       Date
#1:             1           C 2015-10-14
#2:             1           D 2015-10-14
#3:             2           B 2015-10-10
#4:             2           C 2015-10-10
#5:             2           D 2015-10-10
#6:             2           E 2015-10-10
```

### Data

to make it reproducible

```
dt <- fread("fk_ConsumerID   ProductName Date
            1   B   2015.10.12
            1   A   2015.10.14
            1   C   2015.10.18
            1   D   2015.10.19
            2   A   2015.10.10
            2   B   2015.10.12
            2   C   2015.10.14
            2   D   2015.10.18
            2   E   2015.10.19
            3   C   2015.10.14
            3   D   2015.10.18
            3   A   2015.10.19
            4   B   2015.10.10")
dt[, Date := anytime::anydate(Date)]
```

Comment: I'm confused that the answer was downvoted immediately after it was posted. Please, give me an explanation why and what I can do to improve the answer - Thank you.

Comment: It was not me who down voted the answer. I am just trying to figure out why it gives me error on my data set.

Comment: @leva I'm sure you didn't downvote as you weren't online when it happened. However, what error message do you get? Does it happen with the sample data set from your Q? Which version of `data.table` do you have installed?